# How to join one to many tables in Oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join, database-design

I have four tables:
Order, Employee, Supply, Supply_company

```
Order
------------------
Order_id
Order name
Emp_id

Employee
------------------
Emp_id
Emp_name

Supply
--------------------
Supply_id
Order_id
SupplierName

Supply_company
----------------------
Supply_company_id
Supply_id
Supplier_desc
address
```

In these 4 tables one employee has more than one order and one order has many supply ID's and for that one supply ID we have one supplier desc. I wanted to display `Supplier_desc` based on `Emp_id`. I am getting all the descriptions associated with all orders but I need to get specific desc for specific order, I have tried distinct, listagg, inner join and left outer join and used subquery in where clause but I didn't find any solution.

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question

Comment: Add `WHERE Order.Order_id = XXX` to the query.

Comment: 7 questions, 5 with answers, no accepted. Don't expect people to cooperate with you if you do not follor the rules of site.

Answer (score 0):

---

```
SELECT 
    O.EMP_ID,SC.*
FROM
    SUPPLY_COMPANY  SC

INNER JOIN

    SUPPLY S
    ON S.Supply_id=SC.Supply_id

INNER JOIN
    Order O
    ON O.Order_id=S.Order_id 

WHERE O.Emp_id=123
```

Comment: Some explanation of what you're trying to tell the person who asked the question would be useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a particular EMP_ID and an ORDER_ID the following query will get you the EMP_NAME and all SUPPLIER_DESCs associated with that employee and order:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.EMP_ID, e.EMP_NAME, s.SUPPLIER_DESC
  FROM EMPLOYEE e
  INNER JOIN ORDER o
    ON o.EMP_ID = e.EMP_ID
  INNER JOIN SUPPLY s
    ON s.ORDER_ID = o.ORDER_ID
  INNER JOIN SUPPLY_COMPANY c
    ON c.SUPPLY_ID = s.SUPPLY_ID
  WHERE e.EMP_ID = your_emp_id AND
        o.ORDER_ID = your_order_id
```

Here we just walk down from EMPLOYEE, through ORDER and SUPPLY, to SUPPLY_COMPANY where the SUPPLIER_DESC can be found, then use the WHERE clause to filter the results down to the particular employee and order we care about - and since you probably don't want repeated rows we put a DISTINCT on the SELECT criteria to tell us we only want a single example of each unique combination. Just replace `your_emp_id` and `your_order_id` with the EMP_ID and ORDER_ID values you're interested in. Note that if you supply and EMP_ID and ORDER_ID which do not have anything in common on the EMPLOYEE and ORDER tables you'll get nothing returned by this query.

Best of luck.